# Query on multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to create a single query that reads from three tables in the same db.

Tables:

```
1. cm_players
player_id
card_no
club_id
surname
name
birthdate

2. cm_clubs
club_id
prefix
name
address
place
stadium_id
telephone
fax
email
web
contact_person
president
secretary
press_officer
status
image

3. cm_registrations
player_id
surname
name
birthdate
birthplace
club_id
date_from
date_to
amateur
status
```

So, I need to display

```
cm_players.name, 
cm_players.surname, 
cm_clubs.name, 
cm_players.birthdate, 
cm_players.card_no,
```

join cm_players with cm_clubs to get the name of the club, and check in cm_registrations if the user is active.....

I have tried something like:

```
SELECT cm_players.name, cm_players.surname, cm_clubs.name, cm_players.birthdate, cm_players.card_no, cm_registrations.amateur FROM cm_players 
INNER JOIN cm_clubs on cm_players.club_id = cm_clubs.club_id, cm_registrations 
WHERE cm_players.name LIKE '%$name%' AND cm_players.surname LIKE '%$surname%' AND cm_players.player_id = cm_registrations.player_id AND cm_registrations.amateur = 0 ORDER BY cm_players.player_id ASC
```

but no luck...

can anyone help me to build this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we are setting the **table aliases**, and get the column values by using appropriate alias names of that table and we are **using inner joins on two tables** that are clubs and registrations

```
SELECT cmp.name, cmp.surname, cmc.name, cmp.birthdate, cmp.card_no, cmr.amateur 
  FROM cm_players cmp 
  INNER JOIN cm_clubs cmc on cmp.club_id = cmc.club_id
  INNER JOIN cm_registrations cmr on cmp.player_id = cmr.player_id
  WHERE cmp.name LIKE '%$name%' 
  AND cmp.surname LIKE '%$surname%' 
  AND cmr.amateur = 0 
  ORDER BY cmp.player_id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

cm_registrations WHERE cm_players.name LIKE '%$name%' AND cm_players.surname LIKE '%$surname%' AND cm_players.player_id = cm_registrations.player_id AND cm_registrations.amateur = 0 ORDER BY cm_players.player_id ASC
error is after join u use , than cm_registeration change it and try to fix it.